# Resize collection view list cell height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview, uicollectionviewlistcell

I've been working on making the collection view list cell height bigger, and I was wondering how to make the cell height size bigger.
Here is the code from [apple's sample project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views). (Just changed a little bit.)

```
import UIKit

private enum Section: Hashable {
    case main
}

private struct Category: Hashable {
    let icon: UIImage?
    let name: String?
    
    static let music = Category(icon: UIImage(systemName: "music.mic"), name: "Music")
    static let transportation = Category(icon: UIImage(systemName: "car"), name: "Transportation")
    static let weather = Category(icon: UIImage(systemName: "cloud.rain"), name: "Weather")
}

private struct Item: Hashable {
    let category: Category
    let image: UIImage?
    let title: String?
    let description: String?
    init(category: Category, imageName: String? = nil, title: String? = nil, description: String? = nil) {
        self.category = category
        if let systemName = imageName {
            self.image = UIImage(systemName: systemName)
        } else {
            self.image = nil
        }
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
    }
    private let identifier = UUID()
    
    static let all = [
        Item(category: .music, imageName: "headphones", title: "Headphones",
             description: "A portable pair of earphones that are used to listen to music and other forms of audiooooofosdafosdaofdsfsdgfhsdfjhdsfghsdjgfhjdsgfhjsdgfhjsadgfhjsgfhjdsgfjhsgfhjsdgfgsdhjfgsdhjfgshjdkfghsjdfgjhdsfgjdhksgfshdkjafgjhdsgfhjsdagfhjsdagfhjsdgfhsjdgfhjkasdgfhjsadgfhjsagfhjsagfhdsajgfhsjdagfhjsdagfjshdgfhsdagfhjsgfhjsagfhjsagfhjsadgfhjdsagfhjsdgafhjsagdfhjdsaghfjgsadhfjasgdhfjksagfhsjadgfhjdskagfsjadhkfgdsjhkafghjsakgfhsdjakgfhjafgdsafjhkasdgjhfhs."),
        Item(category: .music, imageName: "hifispeaker.fill", title: "Loudspeaker",
             description: "Short.")
    ]
}

class CustomCellListViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>! = nil
    private var collectionView: UICollectionView! = nil
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "List with Custom Cells"
        configureHierarchy()
        configureDataSource()
    }
}

extension CustomCellListViewController {
    private func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let config = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .plain)
        return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: config)
    }
}

extension CustomCellListViewController {
    private func configureHierarchy() {
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }
    
    /// - Tag: CellRegistration
    private func configureDataSource() {
        let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<CustomListCell, Item> { (cell, indexPath, item) in
            cell.updateWithItem(item)
            cell.accessories = [.disclosureIndicator()]
        }
        
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>(collectionView: collectionView) {
            (collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, item: Item) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
            return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: item)
        }
        
        // initial data
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>()
        snapshot.appendSections([.main])
        snapshot.appendItems(Item.all)
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }
}

extension CustomCellListViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}

// Declare a custom key for a custom `item` property.
fileprivate extension UIConfigurationStateCustomKey {
    static let item = UIConfigurationStateCustomKey("com.apple.ItemListCell.item")
}

// Declare an extension on the cell state struct to provide a typed property for this custom state.
private extension UICellConfigurationState {
    var item: Item? {
        set { self[.item] = newValue }
        get { return self[.item] as? Item }
    }
}

// This list cell subclass is an abstract class with a property that holds the item the cell is displaying,
// which is added to the cell's configuration state for subclasses to use when updating their configuration.
private class ItemListCell: UICollectionViewListCell {
    private var item: Item? = nil
    
    func updateWithItem(_ newItem: Item) {
        guard item != newItem else { return }
        item = newItem
        setNeedsUpdateConfiguration()
    }
    
    override var configurationState: UICellConfigurationState {
        var state = super.configurationState
        state.item = self.item
        return state
    }
}

private class CustomListCell: ItemListCell {
    
    private func defaultListContentConfiguration() -> UIListContentConfiguration { return .subtitleCell() }
    private lazy var listContentView = UIListContentView(configuration: defaultListContentConfiguration())
    
    private let categoryIconView = UIImageView()
    private let categoryLabel = UILabel()
    private var customViewConstraints: (categoryLabelLeading: NSLayoutConstraint,
                                        categoryLabelTrailing: NSLayoutConstraint,
                                        categoryIconTrailing: NSLayoutConstraint)?
    
    private func setupViewsIfNeeded() {
        // We only need to do anything if we haven't already setup the views and created constraints.
        guard customViewConstraints == nil else { return }
        
        contentView.addSubview(listContentView)
        contentView.addSubview(categoryLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(categoryIconView)
        listContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let defaultHorizontalCompressionResistance = listContentView.contentCompressionResistancePriority(for: .horizontal)
        listContentView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(defaultHorizontalCompressionResistance - 1, for: .horizontal)
        categoryLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        categoryIconView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let constraints = (
            categoryLabelLeading: categoryLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: listContentView.trailingAnchor),
            categoryLabelTrailing: categoryIconView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoryLabel.trailingAnchor),
            categoryIconTrailing: contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoryIconView.trailingAnchor)
        )
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            listContentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            listContentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            listContentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            categoryLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
            categoryIconView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
            constraints.categoryLabelLeading,
            constraints.categoryLabelTrailing,
            constraints.categoryIconTrailing
        ])
        customViewConstraints = constraints
    }
    
    private var separatorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    private func updateSeparatorConstraint() {
        guard let textLayoutGuide = listContentView.textLayoutGuide else { return }
        if let existingConstraint = separatorConstraint, existingConstraint.isActive {
            return
        }
        let constraint = separatorLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor)
        constraint.isActive = true
        separatorConstraint = constraint
    }
    
    /// - Tag: UpdateConfiguration
    /// sets up the cell’s initial appearance and content
    override func updateConfiguration(using state: UICellConfigurationState) {
        setupViewsIfNeeded()
        
        // Configure the list content configuration and apply that to the list content view.
        var content = defaultListContentConfiguration().updated(for: state)
        content.imageProperties.preferredSymbolConfiguration = .init(font: content.textProperties.font, scale: .large)
        content.image = state.item?.image
        content.text = state.item?.title
        content.secondaryText = state.item?.description
        content.axesPreservingSuperviewLayoutMargins = []
        listContentView.configuration = content
        
        // Get the list value cell configuration for the current state, which we'll use to obtain the system default
        // styling and metrics to copy to our custom views.
        let valueConfiguration = UIListContentConfiguration.valueCell().updated(for: state)
        
        // Configure custom image view for the category icon, copying some of the styling from the value cell configuration.
        categoryIconView.image = state.item?.category.icon
        categoryIconView.tintColor = valueConfiguration.imageProperties.resolvedTintColor(for: tintColor)
        categoryIconView.preferredSymbolConfiguration = .init(font: valueConfiguration.secondaryTextProperties.font, scale: .small)
        
        // Configure custom label for the category name, copying some of the styling from the value cell configuration.
        categoryLabel.text = state.item?.category.name
        categoryLabel.textColor = valueConfiguration.secondaryTextProperties.resolvedColor()
        categoryLabel.font = valueConfiguration.secondaryTextProperties.font
        categoryLabel.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = valueConfiguration.secondaryTextProperties.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory
        
        // Update some of the constraints for our custom views using the system default metrics from the configurations.
        customViewConstraints?.categoryLabelLeading.constant = content.directionalLayoutMargins.trailing
        customViewConstraints?.categoryLabelTrailing.constant = valueConfiguration.textToSecondaryTextHorizontalPadding
        customViewConstraints?.categoryIconTrailing.constant = content.directionalLayoutMargins.trailing
        updateSeparatorConstraint()
    }
}
```

When I run the code, if the secondary text is too short, the list cell becomes too small, and I want to make the cell height at least 80.
[image]

I tried putting another UIView in the cell and added text labels for both cell's text and secondarytext, and add UIimage to the cell since the UIView I put covers the content of the cell and I have to manually put title, secondary text, and image (and use autolayout to configure them). So how can I change the cell height without putting an additional UIView on the cell, so I can still use and display those values?

```
content.image = state.item?.image
content.text = state.item?.title
content.secondaryText = state.item?.description
```

Comment: In collection view delegate functions, there is **SizeForItem** function. You can set cell height here. If you don't know the height then create a temporary label, insert your text to the label & calculate intrinsic height. Let this height is X. Then return max(80.0, X) as height in the delegate function   **SizeForItem**

Comment: @Imran0001 he cant do it because with List Layout a method "sizeForIte" from FlowLayoutDelegate do not calls

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a little involved, but essentially you can calculate and cache the size of your UICollectionViewCell, and provide a default height if its computed height is less than 80.

A contrived example for educational purposes:

```
let sizingCell = UICollectionViewCell()

var sizeCache = [IndexPath: CGSize]()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    if let size = sizeCache[indexPath] {
        return size
    }
    
    // This function represents inflating your cell with its content...
    configure(cell: sizingCell)
    
    // Or whatever width you want your cell to be...
    let width = collectionView.frame.width
    
    // Calculate the height of the cell based on the width...
    let height = sizingCell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: width, height: 0),
                                                                withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required,
                                                                verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel).height
    
    // If your computed height is less than 80, make it such...
    let size = CGSize(width: width, height: max(height, 80))
    
    sizeCache[indexPath] = size
    
    return size
}
```